# React .map and setState weird behavior

Tags: reactjs

The following is a simplified version of the part of the entire code.

The entire app is basically supposed to be a note taking app built on React, and currently I'm stuck on its respective note's editing function.

So the following script part basically is supported to do:

1. Render an array of `<Card />` components based on the App `this.state.notes` array
2. By clicking the `Edit note` button it sets the App `this.state.noteEditingId` state

(so the React instance can know later which generated Card is currnetly being edited by the id)

3. By clicking the `Save Edit` button it tries to update the App `this.state.notes` array with the submitted edit text.

(see, I used a lot of filters to try to achieve this, since I don't have a good idea to how to more nicely achieve this. I believe there should be a nicer way)

4. But the result is not what I expect.

(While it supposed to achieve updating the expected Card component's notes array with the new note instance's new note "note" text,
it updates the notes array with the different notes's note instance's "note" text. I cannot explain this clearly, since this is an idk-what-is-wrong type of issue to me. )

```js
const Card = (props) => { 

    const [noteEditing, setNoteEditing] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div {...props}>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <button onClick={() => {
                            noteEditing ? setNoteEditing(false) : setNoteEditing(true);
                            props.thisApp.setState({ noteEditingId: props.config.id })
                        }}>Edit note</button>
                    </span>
                    
                    {noteEditing
                    ? 
                        <div>
                            <textarea className='__text' />
                            <button onClick={() => {

                                let note = document.querySelector('.__text').value

                                let current_note = props.thisApp.state.notes.filter(a => a.id == props.config.id)[0]
                                let notesAfterRemoved = props.thisApp.state.notes.filter(a => a.id !== props.config.id)

                                if (props.thisApp.state.noteEditingId == props.config.id)
                                {
                                    props.thisApp.setState({
                                        notes: [...notesAfterRemoved, { ...current_note, note: note }]
                                    })
                                }
                            }}>
                                Save Edit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    : ""
                    } 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            notes: [
                {
                    note: "note1.",
                    id: nanoid(), 
                },
                {
                    note: "note2.",
                    id: nanoid(), 
                },
                {
                    note: "note3.",
                    id: nanoid(), 
                },
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Notes ({this.state.notes.length})
                </h2>
                <div className='__main_cards'>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.notes.map((a, i) => {
                            return <Card key={i} className="__card" thisApp={this} config={
                                {
                                    note: a.note, 
                                }
                            } />
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        )
    }
}
```

So what can I do fix to make the part work properly? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to really look at the react docs
https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html, it seems that you're not utilizing react in the right way.

Comment: @BARNOWL I can totally understand that I'm not utilizing react in the right way, I can understand the implementation is terrible. That's exactly why I'm requesting a help here :)

Comment: I don't think in the tutorial there is a sample case like the above case. I did research a lot before posting here.

Comment: I don't understand. When you create the notes give them an ID. Don't create an ID on every render. All the per-note card needs is the `note`; there's a number of ways a text change can be sent back up to the parent component, but I would *NOT* call the parent's `setState` directly: pass a note update function to the child component.

Comment: @DaveNewton The code was wrong. Since I did simplification of my entire code to publish on here SO, I made some mistakes while the modification. I've edited the code and it now should be a corrected code. You're correct, initializing its id on every time does not make sense when I need to refer the id later. Now the nanoid() is on the constructor so called once. It's not the same to my code, but nearly same algorithm

Comment: But what's the difference between calling parentThis.setState() and run props.updateNotes() that ultimately runs this.setState() on the parent?

Comment: @Lime Separation of concerns. Child components should know as little as possible about the environment they’re running in. It also opens up the possibility of a child breaking its parent’s state by accident (or on purpose).

Comment: @Lime I recommend you to clear your react concepts first. Please look at the react documentation or watch tutorials. I have created a sandbox for you code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ypplxq. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the current note also and get rid of the filter in card component:

```
this.state.notes.map((note, i) => {
    return (
        <Card
            key={i}
            className="__card"
            thisApp={this}
            currentNote={note}
        />
    );
})
```

And then remove this:

```
let current_note = props.thisApp.state.notes.filter(a => a.id == props.config.id)[0]
```

And then rather than finding the notes without the edited note you can create a new array with edited data like this:

```
const x = props.thisApp.state.notes.map((n) => {
  if (n.id === props.currentNote.id) {
    return {...n, note}
  }
  return n
})
```

And get rid off this line:

```
let notesAfterRemoved = props.thisApp.state.notes.filter(a => a.id !== props.config.id)
```

Also, change this

```
noteEditing ? setNoteEditing(false) : setNoteEditing(true);
```

To:

```
setNoteEditing(prev => !prev)
```

As it is much cleaner way to toggle the value.

And I believe, there is no need to check that if the noteEditingId is equal to current active note id.

So you can get rid off that also (Correct me if I am wrong!)

Here's the full code:

```
const Card = (props) => {
    const [noteEditing, setNoteEditing] = useState(false);
    const textareaRef = useRef();

    return (
        <div {...props}>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                setNoteEditing((prev) => !prev); // Cleaner way to toggle
                            }}
                        >
                            Edit note
                        </button>
                    </span>

                    {noteEditing && (
                        <div>
                            <textarea className="__text" ref={textareaRef} />
                            <button
                                onClick={() => {
                                    let note = textareaRef.current.value;

                                    const x = props.thisApp.state.notes.map(
                                        (n) => {
                                            if (n.id === props.currentNote.id) {
                                                return { ...n, note };
                                            }
                                            return n;
                                        }
                                    );
                                    props.thisApp.setState({
                                        notes: x,
                                    });
                                }}
                            >
                                Save Edit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            notes: [
                {
                    note: "note1.",
                    id: nanoid(),
                },
                {
                    note: "note2.",
                    id: nanoid(),
                },
                {
                    note: "note3.",
                    id: nanoid(),
                },
            ],
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Notes ({this.state.notes.length})</h2>
                <div className="__main_cards">
                    <div>
                        {this.state.notes.map((note, i) => {
                            return (
                                <Card
                                    key={i}
                                    className="__card"
                                    thisApp={this}
                                    currentNote={note}
                                />
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
                                        }
                                        );
                                        props.thisApp.setState({
                                            notes: x,
                                        });
                                    }
                                }}
                            >
                                Save Edit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            notes: [
                {
                    note: "note1.",
                    id: nanoid(),
                },
                {
                    note: "note2.",
                    id: nanoid(),
                },
                {
                    note: "note3.",
                    id: nanoid(),
                },
            ],
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Notes ({this.state.notes.length})</h2>
                <div className="__main_cards">
                    <div>
                        {this.state.notes.map((note, i) => {
                            return (
                                <Card
                                    key={i}
                                    className="__card"
                                    thisApp={this}
                                    currentNote={note}
                                />
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful for you!